# Multiple databases and collections mongodump

Tags: bash, mongodb, mongodump

I have something like this:

```
dbs=$(mongo --quiet --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames()" --host exemple.com | \ 
            grep '"' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ',')

for db in $dbs; do
    cols=$(mongo --quiet --eval "print(db.getCollectionNames())" $db \
                  --host exemple.com | tr ',' ' ')
    for col in $cols; do
        mongodump --host example.com -q "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" \
                   -d $dbs -c $col --out /data/
   done
done
```

I'm getting:

> positional arguments not allowed

How can I use `mongodump` for all collections in all databases ?

Comment: Double quote all your shell variables, `$dbs`, `$db`, `$cols`, `$col`. It may not solve the problem, but useful in bye-passing trivial issues

Comment: `grep '"' | tr -d '"' | tr -d ','` can be simplified to:  `tr -d '",'`.

Comment: `grep` and `tr` can be replace by `jq -r '.[]'` if you're into that sort of thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a working script:

```
  dbs=`mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames()" | grep '"' | tr -d '",' `


    for db in $dbs; do
        col=`mongo  $db --host example.com --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | tr -d ',"[]' `
        for collection in $col; do
          mongodump --host example.com -q '{_id: {$gt: 10}}' -d $db -c $collection --out dump

       done
    done
```

from [**mongodump documentation**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump) :

> --query , -q
>
> Provides a JSON document as a query that optionally limits the documents
>   included in the output of mongodump. You must enclose the query in single quotes (e.g. ') to ensure that it does not interact with your shell environment.

Comment: for local mongodb is working, but for remote I get the local db's and collections also

dbs=`mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames()" | grep '"' | tr -d '",' `

    echo $dbs
        for db in $dbs; do
            col=`mongo  $db --host example.com --quiet --eval 
    "db.getCollectionNames()" | tr -d ',"[]' `
            for collection in $col; do
              mongodump --host example.com -q '{_id: {$gt: 10}}' -d $db -c 
    $collection --out dump

           done
        done

Comment: @basante make sure to update the host name in the 2 `mongo` calls and in the mongodump, and to upadte the query according to your needs

Comment: yes of course I change the hostname, but still I'm getting the local dbs. Can you please show me an example, maybe I'm not setting up the --host correctly

Answer (score 2):

For multiple database.

```
dbs=( z2p stackoverflow poststodos)  
for c in ${dbs[@]}
do
mongodump -d  $c  --out ~/backups/dump
done
```

Comment: Very clever! Just note to add  "--authenticationDatabase admin " for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

you may give this script a try, which provides a function called dump_by_filter

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# sudo apt install mongo-tools
# sudo apt install mongo-client

# dump(uri:string,col:string,out:string)
function dump {
    local uri=$1
    local col=$2
    local out=$3

    mongodump --forceTableScan  --uri=$uri  -c $col --out $out
}

# load(uri:string,dir:string)
function load {
    local uri=$1
    local dir=$2
    mongorestore --drop --uri=$uri $dir
}

# list_col(uri:string,filter:string)
function list_col {
   local res=`echo show collections |mongo $1 --quiet |grep $2` 
   echo $res
}

# dump(uri:string,filter:string,out:string)
function dump_by_filter {
    local uri=$1
    local filter=$2
    local out=$3

    local cols=$(list_col $uri $filter)
    for col in $cols; do
        dump $uri $col $out
        echo dump $col to $out
    done
}

FROM_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/a"
TO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/b"

DIR="./out"
dump_by_filter $FROM_URL xx $DIR
load $TO_URL $DIR
```

i place it [here](https://gist.github.com/woodgear/1d4053be67ce2456d1113509bd04b708)